# How to call a JavaScript function from different HTML File?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a link from a separate HTML file to show a specific auto JavaScript-hidden element. The page shows 8 separate buttons that when clicked it shows a hidden div element.

JavaScipt function code:

```
    function tr() {
        var x = document.getElementById("tr");
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Once again I am trying to call this function from within a separate HTML file.

Thank you!

Edit: Yes sorry should've mentioned I'm extremely inexperienced with JavaScript. Now, when I make it into an object it seems as though the fuction still isn't getting called. Is there anything I need to include to make this object global?

```
var name = {
    a : function tr() {
        (...)
    }
}
```

how I'm calling it:

```
<button onclick="name.a()" class="button">
```

Comment: Now, what is the actual problem here? Just do `tr()`, but notice, that the function in another file must be global (or inside a global object).

Comment: In a `load` Event, if your Script tags are in your head you have access to the other scripts. Just make sure the variables and functions you want to access are scoped above the load.

Comment: After the edit, there's nothing you need to specifically do to define a global object or function, just declare it in the global scope. If the object method in the example is not called, take a look at Network Tab in the DevTools, you'll find out whether the external file is loaded or not.

Comment: Ummm ... providing the real name of the object is something else than `name`. Global `name` is the name of the window, and it is type protected (it's always a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following this you can call a JavaScript function from different HTML File:

```
<script src="demo.js"></script>
```

here demo.js is your javaScript file name.
and in this code add `id="tr"` and `onclick="tr()"`.

```
<button onclick="tr()" class="button" id="tr">demo btn</button>
```

example:

```js
function tr() {
    var x = document.getElementById("tr");
    alert("function is call");

    // if (x.style.display === "block") {
    //     x.style.display = "none";
    // } else {
    //     x.style.display = "block";
    // }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="tr()" class="button" id="tr">demo btn</button>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```